# Is having a loop in C++ constructor a good Idea?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was writing code for my homework. So as I finished one of my classes I ran into a question. Is having a loop to assign values to array a good idea?
This is my class. I was thinking of making either loop in the constructor or create a function which would assign values later, by calling it manually.

Are these choices different? if yes, Which choice is better and why?

```
class Mule
{
    private:
        int numofMules;
        int MapSize;
        MuleNode* field;
        MuleNode* mules;
    public:
        void random_positions();
        void motion();
        void print_field();
        Mule(int nofMules, int mSize)
        {
            numofMules = nofMules;
            MapSize = mSize;
            mules = new MuleNode[numofMules];
            field = new MuleNode[MapSize*MapSize];
            for(i = 0; i < numofMules; i++)                              
            {
                mules[i].ID = i+1;
            }
            random_positions();
        }   
}
```

Edited the code because of the problem with allocation of one dimensional array at compilation time and recreated 2 dimensional array in 1 dimensional using formulas.

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+  
| i = j * w + i | x = i % w | y = i / w |  w - width of the 2 dimentional array
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Conclusion**: As the question was marked as *opinion-based*, I guess it means that there is no big difference in using loop in the constructor or creating a function which would assign values later.

If there are any facts or opinions about this question worth sharing, please comment or write your answer.

Comment: It's neither here nor there. If a loop is the best way to initialize your data, use a loop.

Comment: Why would you think it matters? If there's a reason for it to matter then you already know what direction to take.

Comment: There is no problem with that, but be aware, you've got a typo at MapSize = mSIze

Comment: @jordsti Thx ^^ I would have probably noticed that and spent 6 hours finding problem.

Comment: @mah I don't know if it matters and as Im curious I wan't to find the answer.

Comment: It's somewhat orthogonal to your question, but be aware that you can't define array members with a dynamic size like this. You can only use a compile-time constant for the size of an array member, not the value of another member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not necessarily anything terrible about having a loop in a ctor.

At the same time, it's worth considering whether those items you're initializing couldn't/shouldn't be objects that know how to initialize themselves instead of creating uninitialized instances, then writing values into them.

As you've written it, the code doesn't really seem to make much sense though. The class name is `Mule`, but based on the ctor, it's really more like a collection of Mules. A Mule should be exactly that: one mule. A collection of N mules should be something like a `std::vector<Mule>`. A Mule that's really a collection of Mules is a poor idea.

You should also at least consider using `std::vector` instead of an array (assuming that you end up with a collection of items in the class at all, of course).

Answer (score -4):

In general, not a good idea, but some constructors *require* a loop (example, initializing an array in heap, which is initialized in the constructor). But not all constructors are called so often (singletons, for example, called only once per process).

In the end, it depends on the class and program/object design.

Your particular class appears like it will be created only once per process. So my take is that it is OK. If that is not the case, then we have to evaluate it on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: _"not a good idea ... evaluate it on a case-by-case basis"_ -- Why is it not a good idea? Evaluate based on what criteria?

Comment: What *else* would you do if it was called often? Just let the program read uninitialized data? It has to be initialized at some point. Why not let the constructor do it?

Comment: I am not sure if you folks even read my comment. I do qualify it quite clearly. Yes, I am aware of your reps.